# Why is my tulsi plant drying up?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, basil

[image]

[image]
There are traces of white spots, leaves turning brown from the edge and the plant is dying off. (I don't see evident signs of spider mites, which are present on my other plants and I am using need oil for it).. so I am unable to figure out how to maintain this plant..

Thr are 3 seperate plants in a single pot, all plants are about 3 months old.
We are currently sparcely watering daily, to keep the soil moist and the plant gets direct sunlight only for about 2 hours but indirect sunlight for 8-10 hours..

Comment: Give [6 hours of **sunshine**](https://practicalselfreliance.com/how-to-grow-tulsi/). An Indian herb isn't going to get by on 2. Show us pics of the spots and browning. Browning is a root issue, maybe watering daily is too much. Move one into a small pot at the window and compare.

Answer (score 1):

Too many faults to consider here:

1. Probably the biggest issue being the soil you used as a potting medium is red dirt. Such pure red dirt is void of organic matter in soil. Try adding mustard cake and mulch or cow dung mix to the soil, you can experiment with worm castings for an additional benefit. Pure red soils have too high iron content which is apparently visible in curled and dried leaves as also, pure red soils can't retain ample moisture.
2. Lack of sunlight, like said by @Yosef Baskin will cause your Tulsi to become lanky and weak, albeit that, I think they'll compensate for it once they grow or seasons change.
3. Prune your top growth. Yes! I know it feels a tad bit bad to chop your plants, but plants (especially herbs) are evolved to be eaten by animals. And thus an injury to them will cause them to release hormones and will direct the plant to grow more meristems and to branch more thus bringing a growth spurt to your plants.